# Failed to install CorePlot 2.0 via cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, core-plot

I have been using CorePlot 1.5.1 using cocoapod in my Xcode project without issue. Now I need to upgrade to CorePlot 2.0 because I need the touch up/down on same event. I tried doing that by editing PodFile by either:

```
pod 'CorePlot', '~> 2.0'
```

and

```
target 'ERPTests' do
pod 'CorePlot'
end
```

First way I got error "`CorePlot (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`". Second way I got the 1.5.1 version. My cocoa pod is 0.35.0. I googled and no related post on this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 2.0 release of Core Plot (yet). Use the following line in your podfile to point at the `release-2.0` branch:

```
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.0'
```

There is a combined header file that works for both Mac and iOS apps. You can also use the `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` header for iOS projects.

```
#import "CorePlot.h"
```

Comment: Hi Eric - there's a run-time error after updating to CorePlot release 2.0. There's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS stuck at the class method definition (+(instancetype)plotRangeWithLocation:(NSNumber *)loc length:(NSNumber *)len). I did a clean build but the problem still exist.

Comment: Note that some of the API changed on the `release-2.0` branch. See the [change log](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/release-2.0/documentation/changelog.markdown) for details. Make sure you're passing an `NSNumber` to that method. The old version took an `NSDecimal`.

Comment: Error still exists after I changed to NSNumber (plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:xMin] length:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:xMax]];). Error message is "Sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSDecimal'

Comment: The app isn't linked agains a 2.0 version of Core Plot. Have you tried a clean build after updating the pod?

Comment: I've done both "Clean Build Folder" and "Clean" under Product in Xcode.. still same error.

Comment: Eric - Is that actually a bug (similar to this problem: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/87)? Will there be any termporary fix? Please help...

Comment: It might be a bug—I'm looking into it. See issues [163](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/163) and [164](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/164) for more info.

Comment: hi Eric I saw you updated the header file in the Github. Do I just do a "pod update"?

Comment: I just did a "pod update" and clean build, but it's still showing the same error........

Comment: Which error are you seeing? Does CocoaPods display any warnings when you update the pod? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: It's the same error message: "Sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSDecimal' when I'm passing NSNumber to the method "plotRangeWithLocation". I'm using Xcode 6.2. I didn't see any warning while updating the pod. Though I saw that the CorePlot is updating to 0.99.99 instead of 2.0 in the Cocoapod update log. I am using the string you instructed in your reply in my Podfile.

Comment: If you have the right (release-2.0) version, the `CPTPlotRange` header should define these two methods: `+plotRangeWithLocation:length:` and `+plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:lengthDecimal:`. The first one takes `NSNumber` values and the second one takes `NSDecimal` values.

Comment: Hi Eric - I just tried to update again. It said the orthogonalCoordinateDecimal property is not available in CPTXYAxis object type anymore??

Comment: On the release-2.0 branch, `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal ` has been renamed to `orthogonalPosition` and the type changed to `NSNumber`. This is one of several changes made to the API to make it easier to work with from Swift.

Comment: Finally it works! My previous attempt failed because I was still pointing to the old Coreplot header file. For the sake of other people looking at this thread in future: you need to change the header file from #import "CorePlotHeaders/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" to #import "CorePlot.h" if you are including the CP library via Cocoapods install.